# coldfusion using cfoutput with a variable in a variable name

Tags: coldfusion

I've got multiple files that have are using the same template cfm files

I have chunks of content of the pages in a template file `content.cfm` that I can retrieve through various variable names : `content_home` `content_contact` `title_home` `title_contact`

I'd like to have an intermediary template file that can call the `content_#id#` and `title_#id#` based on the provided `id`.

the `id` is defined with the template in home.cfm and contact.cfm

The issue I'm having is that I cannot reference a variable using a variable as part of the name such as `#content_#id##`

Comment: Honestly? If this is not self-educational project, I would highly recommend to avoid inventing the bicycle and use some framework. Possibly very simple https://github.com/seancorfield/fw1

Comment: might want to look into using `<cfmodule>`, what CF was designed to use for, but it's hell when it comes to maintaining it.

Comment: I'll have a look at this framework. I'm using cfWheels for a more robust application, but am worried that for such a simple site I'll use more time learning the framework than doing the tedious copy-pasting

Comment: Stop worrying. Look at [FW/1](https://github.com/seancorfield/fw1/wiki) - it's not hard and there's an [active mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/framework-one/) (and here) where you can ask for help if you do get stuck. (It might be less time to copy-paste now, but doing that _will_ come back to bite you later.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Abstracting from the purpose (using mature framework helps a lot) you can achieve referencing dynamic variables using structure notation: `variables["content_" & id]` for your case

Comment: how deliciously simple,  dakujem!  (on a side note - blava 4 life!)

Answer (score 5):

I don't quite understand the question (or indeed, that you're asking a question ;-)

However are you just asking whether in parser.cfm you can do this:

```
<cfinclude template="content_#page#.cfm">
```

?

Well: yes you can.  Try it!

BTW, I concur with the person who suggested you don't reinvent the wheel.  Have a look at FW/1.  It'll do all this stuff (and a lot more) for you.

Comment: in this case I would need a separate template/content cfm file for every page. While It would be easier to maintain content void of a lot of the tags, I'm looking to use one file for all.

Comment: Also concur on reinvention of the wheel. Seek out FW/1.